# While using redux in react, the moment I use <Provider></Provider> in my code it throws weird error. what's this?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm creating an app using react js, using react-redux as state manager. I have created a file to store all my states at one place and while using the Provider in my app.js I'm getting this weird huge error. I'm a beginner and learning redux and in the beginning I am not able to understand this. Please help someone as soon as possible.

my app.js looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Contacts from './components/contacts/Contacts';
import AddContact from './components/contacts/AddContact';
import EditContact from './components/contacts/EditContact';
import Header from './components/layout/Header';
import About from './components/pages/About';
import NotFound from './components/pages/NotFound';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import store from './store';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
          <div className="App">
            <Header branding="Contact Manager" />
            <div className="container">
              <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Contacts} />
                <Route exact path="/contact/add" component={AddContact} />
                <Route exact path="/contact/edit/:id" component={EditContact} />
                <Route exact path="/about" component={About} />
                <Route component={NotFound} />
              </Switch>
            </div>
          </div>
        </Router>
      </Provider>     
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

if I don't use Provider here, app runs. Screenshot of errors is attached.

The errors I get:

```
Provider
C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/contactmanager_redux/node_modules/react-redux/es/components/Provider.js:11
   8 | var store = _ref.store,
   9 |     context = _ref.context,
  10 |     children = _ref.children;
> 11 | var contextValue = useMemo(function () {
  12 |   var subscription = createSubscription(store);
  13 |   subscription.onStateChange = subscription.notifyNestedSubs;
  14 |   return {
View compiled
mountIndeterminateComponent
C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/contactmanager_redux/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:13380
  13377 |   }
  13378 | 
  13379 |   ReactCurrentOwner.current = workInProgress;
> 13380 |   value = fn(props, context);
  13381 | }
  13382 | // React DevTools reads this flag.
  13383 | workInProgress.effectTag |= PerformedWork;
View compiled
beginWork
C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/contactmanager_redux/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:13820
  13817 | 
  13818 | switch (workInProgress.tag) {
  13819 |   case IndeterminateComponent:
> 13820 |     return mountIndeterminateComponent(current, workInProgress, renderExpirationTime);
  13821 |   case FunctionalComponent:
  13822 |     return updateFunctionalComponent(current, workInProgress);
  13823 |   case ClassComponent:
```

[Here is the screenshot of errors:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PB9EZ.jpg)

Here is the code in my store.js :

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware, compose} from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers/index';

const initialState = {};

const middleware = [thunk];

const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState, compose(applyMiddleware(...middleware), window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()));

export default store;
```

following is the code in the rootReducer from './reducers/index' :

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import contactReducer from './contactReducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  contact: contactReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

and contactReducer from './contactReducer':

```
const initialState = {};

export default function(state = initialState, action){
  switch(action.type){
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: Add the `store` content to could be check

Comment: Can you show your store file `import store from './store';`? It would seem thats the issue - your not creating, or exporting, your store correctly. It say in error that `object is not a function` meaning your `store` is not a function but rather an object. Updating the question with your `./store` file could help us identify what is wrong.

Comment: I think there is something wrong with your store export

Comment: I have edited and added the code in my store.js too. please review my question.

Comment: @davoodSandoghsaz I have edited and added the code in my store.js too. please review my question.

Comment: @Lith I have edited and added the code in my store.js too. please review my question.

Comment: @SuyashVashishtha I have edited and added the code in my store.js too. please review my question.

Answer (score 0):

The issue happens because of your version. Not all versions are compatable with eatch other and it seems your react and react-dom is not compatable with react-redux. You need to update it. Type this into your terminal in your project root

```
npm upgrade react react-dom
```

This should update your packages and work fine after a restart.

In addition, I took a look at your project and here is few quick TIPs:

**1st.** `.js` is for javascript. If you are returning html (for example your APP.js file) it should end in `.jsx`. The jsx means javascript xml. While it works... thats not how it suppost to be. Any file with a return of HTML should be `.jsx` or `.tsx` for typescript.

2nd. DONT put `node_modules` folder in your repository. Its a folder where your packages are stored. You dont need it. The `package.json` keeps track of what packages you need of what version. Whenever you freshly pull a project simply do `npm i` (short for `npm install`) and all the packages will be downloaded for you.

3nd. Dont put `package-lock.json`. Its uneeded. It get generated whenever yo urun `npm i` to install nay package.

4th. Nowadays a standart is ES6. Meaning all the classes you have - would recommend switching to arrow functions. Instead of

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    ..code..
  }
}
```

it would be

```
const App = () => {
  return {
    ..code..
  }
}
```

When working with states and lots of logic, arrow functions are cleaner IMO.

5th. clean code! There are guides on this on a basic scale. There is a hard limit of how many characters you should have in a single line - break up your code. There are rules of when you should break your code and in what section. This all matters. While the code works - not correctly formatted code can be hard to read and debug. If your using a visual studio code (VSC) I woudl recommend an extension `Prettier - code formatter`. Its a life savior!

In addition dont do

```
if (name === "") {
  this.setState({ errors: { name: "Name is required" } });
  return;
}

if (email === "") {
  this.setState({ errors: { email: "Email is required" } });
  return;
}

if (phone === "") {
  this.setState({ errors: { phone: "Phone is required" } });
  return;
}
```

If you need so many IFs then use `switch`. But in your case you can simply do a single function to check if its empty or not and a loop to check each field that is required. Or better yet - use build in `required` tag on form elements. You can give `required` parameter to `<input />` to make it required on form submit. and make a custom error message for it. There are many ways to handle it and yours is not the way. Would suggest looking more into it :)

Hope these short tips help and the update help your issue :)

Comment: thanks for your response. I am still struggling with redux. could you please see. The error is about the <Provider></Provider>.  In the store I have done everything possible. If you get time please check the code on my github, 
https://github.com/And4Web/contact_manager_redux

Comment: @And4Web srr for the time. I got back from work and looked at your code. I found the issue. Hope it helps. I also included some tips that i noticed real quickly. Hope they help. All of it is in the edited answer above :) hope it helps

Comment: Thanks a lot. you solved the issue. I am a beginner developer and still learning. Your advice is so precious to me. I will try to follow everything you told me to become a great developer just like you.